# MapBox sqlite layer from OSM

Tags: sqlite, openstreetmap, mapbox

New to MapBox.

I have read the tuto on how to create a layer from OSM which relies on a PostGIS connection. Tried it. So far, so good.
Nonetheless, given the very limited magnitude of the project i'm working on (single user...), i'd really rather avoid having to have a pgsql instance running just for that. sqlite comes across as an option of course!

Can someone help with the following questions:

- Any reason why sqlite would not do the job ? The data set i'm pulling from OSM is about 30MB
- Any recommandable and tried script to convert OSM .xml or .pbf to .sqlite ? There is a bunch of osm2sqlite out there on github and where-else, but can't see any reference to them that let me think they will still be maintained in a foreseeable future...
- How straightforward will it be to link such sqlite output to a tile mill layer ? Clearly, I have no idea on the underlying data model and subsequent sql statement to bring it across...

Many thanks

Laurent

Answer (score 2):

Use mbtiles (this is basically sqlite if you didn't know).

1. Mbtiles will work perfectly for you. In fact Mapbox [uses it for their maps](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/building-mapbox-fast-map-hosting-stack/)
2. As you've seen from that link, tilemill can export your project to mbtiles . Personally I would import to postgres using imposm3, it's fairly fast and doesn't use up ask your memory. After importing I'd style the map with tilemill then use it to generate mbtiles.
   Seems like you're already comfortable with the first 2 steps of this. The [docs](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/crashcourse/exporting/) cover the exporting step
3. Never used mbtiles but I can't see why you would have difficulty with them.

**Nb** In the future you'll be better off asking questions these at [gis.stackexchange.com/](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)